# React Redux + Socket.IO + Create React App

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, webpack, redux, create-react-app

I want to start by saying this is my first project with React Redux and Socket.IO. 
I also have no knowledge of what it takes to construct proper build, start, and test scripts. My knowledge of webpack is also pretty limited to the point where I only really feel comfortable adding or removing loaders. I find a lot of the pre-configurations in create react app to be very helpful; jest, hot loading, build outputs. As you know react-create-app uses webpackdev server. However, for the server side portion of my app I have a socket.io server similar to this configuration.

```
import Server from 'socket.io';

export function startServer(store) {
  const io = new Server().attach(8090);

  store.subscribe(
    () => io.emit('state', store.getState().toJS())
  );

  io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.emit('state', store.getState().toJS());
    socket.on('action', store.dispatch.bind(store));
  });

}
```

Basically I am looking for a resource or even better an explanation that can help me incorporate socket io and redux with the best parts of react-create-app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting rid of webpack entirely and removed the scripts. I rewrite the test script to a simple jest command. Followed this to finish up the socket.io config. https://teropa.info/blog/2015/09/10/full-stack-redux-tutorial.html

You can also see how the application looks like right now. https://github.com/donleyac/react-card-engine

Answer (score 0):

For the client side I suggest to manage the project following this guide.

[Redux guide](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react)

For the socket.io integration I suggest using my two redux middlewares that allows you to subscribe events and emit messages using the redux paradigm.

[socket.io-emitter-middleware](https://github.com/epavanello/socket.io-emitter-middleware)

[socket.io-subscriber-middleware](https://github.com/epavanello/socket.io-subscriber-middleware)

You can install them via the following commands

```
npm i socket.io-emitter-middleware

npm i socket.io-subscriber-middleware
```

and following the README from github documentation for the usage.

The server part could go well.
You must not confuse the create-react-app environment with the client/server architecture. The create-react-app environment is only "client side".

You need connect your client react app with the node.js server via socket.io.

I suggest you to start from the socket.io documentation.

[Socket.io Introduction](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/)